# How can I declare a function parameter that can be a string or a function, in Kotlin?

Tags: dynamic, types, kotlin, kotlin-interop

In the following function, I want to pass to it attributes for a html tag. These attributes can be strings (`test("id", "123")`) or functions (`test("onclick", {_ -> window.alert("Hi!")})`):

```
fun test(attr:String, value:dynamic):Unit {...}
```

I tried to declare the parameter `value` as `Any`, the root type in Kotlin. But functions aren't of type `Any`. Declaring the type as `dynamic` worked, but

- `dynamic` isn't a type. It just turns off typing checking for the parameter.
- `dynamic` only works for kotlin-js (Javascript).

How can I write this function in Kotlin (Java)? How do function types relate to Any? Is there a type that includes both function types and `Any`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could just overload the function:

```
fun test(attr: String, value: String) = test(attr, { value })

fun test(attr: String, createValue: () -> String): Unit {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to create a variable for both types? Like `var x:dynamic` where `x` can be a string or a function? `x="foo"; x= {print (...)}`

Answer (score 2):

You could write:

```
fun test(attr: String, string: String? = null, lambda: (() -> Unit)? = null) {
  if(string != null) { // do stuff with string }
  if(lambda != null) { // do stuff with lambda }
  // ...
}
```

And then call the function in the following ways:

```
test("attr")
test("attr", "hello")
test("attr", lambda = { println("hello") })
test("attr") { println("hello") }
test("attr", "hello", { println("hello") })
test("attr", "hello") { println("hello") }
```